# No output from /dev/serial0 (RPI 4)

Tags: pi-4, uart

I am also doing similar project with raspberry pi 4 (bullseye version) and neo 6m module. I have followed all the steps given in https://sparklers-the-makers.github.io/blog/robotics/use-neo-6m-module-with-raspberry-pi/ but I do not see any output when I do sudo cat /dev/serial0. It simply hangs, does not crash pi. Ctrl+C brings the unix prompt back,
The blue light on the antenna is blinking as suggested by the article.

I don't know which other settings I am missing. Here is the gist of the tutorial:

0. I am trying to read the GPS data by using Raspberry Pi 4 + Neo 6M GPS module
1. I edited /boot/config.txt and added
   dtparam=spi=on
   dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt
   core_freq=250
   enable_uart=1
   force_turbo=1 at the bottom of the file
2. I created a backup of /boot/cmdline.txt and in the new cmdline.txt file, added
   dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles
3. After rebooting, sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0 hangs.
   I checked that /dev/serial0 is linked to ttyAMA0.
   I also used raspi-config to disable login and lastly, I also performed
   sudo systemctl stop serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
   sudo systemctl disable serial-getty@ttyAMA0.service
   but sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0 or /dev/serial0 still hangs.
   Note that the blue light on the antenna is blinking which means the antenna is receiving data. Is it transmitting the data to pi? I don't know. Is there anyway to find it out other than sudo cat /dev/ttyAMA0?

Comment: This is a rather poor tutorial. It is old (pre Bullseye) and advises you to put things in config.txt which are obsolete. You should configure using `raspi-config`